# Using hirb in rake task

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, hirb

I would like to get nice printing by `hirb` in rake task. But I can't figure out how to setup `hirb` to print the `ActiveRecord` results.

```
task :t2 => :environment do
  require 'hirb'
  Hirb.enable
  result = Task.select('project_id, COUNT(*) AS counter').group('project_id').order('counter DESC')
  puts Hirb::Helpers::Table.render(result)
  Hirb.disable
end
```

I've got error "Table must be an array of hashes or array of arrays"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
puts Hirb::Helpers::AutoTable.render(active_record_object)
```